# FileMaker Pro 10 - ODBC/JDBC - Query Parse Error that doesn't make sense

Tags: sql, jdbc, odbc, filemaker

I'm trying to run this simple query over a JDBC connection:

```
select _fk_DeptBillTo from WorkOrder
```

And I'm getting back this error:

```
 09:31:39  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -201, SQL State: HY000]  [DataDirect][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][DataDirect][ODBC FileMaker driver][FileMaker]Parse Error in SQL
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

I've verified that this field exists.  I've checked the spelling and case about 20 times :-(.  Also I've successfully run this query replacing _fk_DeptBillTo with a different field.

I'm not sure but the common pattern so far is that I get this error when I use fields that start with an underscore.

Is there a way to quote field names, like how in MySQL you do select `somefield` from ...?  If so would that help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question... either avoid leading underscores or quote the field names. Try either double quote " or single quote ' and see which one works.

I ran into a similar problem with somebody who had named their field 'table' - that's a reserved word, so it was always failing.

Comment: You're right.  Thanks.  It looks like double quote works.  I wouldn't have guessed double quote would be the right character to use.